# Retrieve and load images from Firebase Storage without using Realtime Database using while loop instead?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, while-loop, firebase-storage

I am developing a photo gallery app in Swift right now using Firebase to store the images. My goal is to load all the images in a collection view when the view loads.

The images are stored in folders called images_(user email)_(user id). The user uploads images which are stored in the Firebase Storage with the names image0.png, image1.png, image2.png, etc. Right now, I have successfully created accounts and stored the images. Now, I am trying to load the images in a collection view in the viewDidLoad(). I am not using the Firebase Realtime Database because I feel it would be overkill for what I am trying to accomplish.

```
while (isDownloading == true) {

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference();
        let imageLoadRef = storageRef.child(("images_" + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)! + "_" + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) + "/image" + String(self.imageCount) + ".png")

        imageLoadRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error { 
                self.isDownloading = false
            } else {
                let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                //Updates collection view with loaded image
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

                //moves on to next image
                self.imageCount += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

As soon as the view loads, I run a while loop that iterates through all the images in the user's folder. Since I don't have any way to get the number of images in the folder, I had to use a while loop and break it when the next image is not found. For example, if there are only 5 images in the folder, the code will return an error when it tries to load the sixth nonexistent image. When this happens, I try to catch the error and break the while loop by setting the condition isDownloading to false.

However, the issue I am running in to is that the while loop never breaks even though it should return an error and set isDownloading to false.

To clarify, the imageCount variable is increased with each iteration of the while loop to get the next image in the folder. So when imageCount = 1 for example, the code will try to load a photo with name "image1.png". However, if it doesn't exist, it catches the error and breaks the while loop.

I know the way I structured it is a little confusing but I find it more efficient than using downloadURLs and the Firebase Database.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know will it work or not you can just give it a try For now and let me know if issue exists

```
//Loop is Fine
while (isDownloading == true) {
        //Provided Required References 
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference();
        //Name of file to download 
        let imageLoadRef = storageRef.child(("images_" + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)! + "_" + (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) + "/image" + String(self.imageCount) + ".png")
        //handler That Run in async Mode 
        imageLoadRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            //Here I think mistake is 
            if let error = error { 
                //You are catching error But not handling data error
                self.isDownloading = false
            } 
            else {
                    if data != nil{ // if image found 
                       //here you need to check weather this handler is returning data o not as you got error of no data So Do All functioning here 
                       // User photo here
                       let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                       //Updates collection view with loaded image
                       self.collectionView.reloadData()

                       //moves on to next image
                       self.imageCount += 1
                    }
                    else {
                       //If Image is not found This will cause you an error which you will handle , According to me this was need to be handled
                       self.isDownloading = false
                    }

            }
        }
    }
```

In case this solution is not working You can check Below Demo project on GitHub and use this Method to easily manage images stored under a user

```
Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/FirebaseDemo
```

Comment: Sadly, it did not fix the issue. I added your changes however, nothing seemed to change. I added a few debug print statements in the code but it seems to skip through imageLoadRef.getData part. The imageCount did not increase either. It remained at 0 but the while loop kept on running.

Comment: This Handler runs Asynchronous way Are you not getting any Output After removing breakpoints ? Can I see your Code file, As when I did I saved the links that are uploaded from Userid in its database with a Chile "imageLinks" and Get images from there , it bigger the size of data but its actually reliable instead of passing names to Handler Should I show you what I did ?

Comment: The code stops because the while loop continues on infinitely. The condition isDownloading is never changed to false, it remains true.

Comment: Yes I think it will run infinite as till your while loop dont stop Handler will not execute as while loop is still performing its action on mainQueue , You can use a different way to get images if. you like I will suggest you the way

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean. Is there any way to fix this or should I try a different approach?

Comment: if possible try a different approach Should I suggest you a way for this ?

Comment: Yes, do you have any suggestions? Thank you I am still new to fire base

Comment: Okay I will send you a demo Project for this You can have a look

Comment: Answer is updated with link for project please check , You can use that code too , I checked its working

Comment: Method or project ?